# ASP.NET Core - Assets file doesn't have a target for .NETCoreApp 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to compile my application to run on Core 3.0 (NOT 3.1)

And I'm able to compile and run fine locally, but when I do a publish it gives me:

> Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\dev...\project.assets.json' doesn't
>   have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. Ensure that restore has
>   run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks
>   for your project.

But I'm not trying to make it run on 3.1, I need 3.0 (To maintain compatibility with other projects)

Is it possible to find out what causes it to look for 3.1 instead of 3.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check your build configuration

Comment: It happened to be the publish configuration, but i have to manually change the publish profile file as oppose to changing it in UI. Because UI showed all correct values despite incorrect ones in publish profile

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue after upgrading from 3.1 to Net 6.0 where it will Build but not Publish. I then updated my existing Publish profiles to Net 6.0 as well and everything is working now.

[Publish Profile Setting to change as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErxyZ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

The fastest way for me was deleting the assets file and running a `dotnet restore` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) in the NuGet "package manager console" and had everything run smooth

Answer (score 7):

1. **Update** all DLLs to version 3.0
2. **Check** your build configuration
3. **Edit** `FolderProfile.pubxml` and change `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>`

Answer (score 6):

Updating the nuget version fixed it for me:

```
nuget update -self
```

If you prefer to update the nuget version in Visual Studio, just follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-update) steps.

Answer (score 2):

Update visual studio this was a Microsoft bug and they fixed the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with the current version of VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I faced this while updating from .Net core 3.1 to .Net 6. So I edited my publish profile and set the **Target Framework** to .Net6 and it resolved the problem for me and API got published. [image]